# GIMP: creating a 1 pixel wide line

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to create 1 pixel wide borders for some web buttons.
I've tried to use the GIMP path tool to do this but I can't figure out how to get it looking right. See attached image.

1 - copied from a button I found on a web-page. This is what I want - single pixel horizontal and vertical lines with feathering on the curved bits.

2 - path that I used to generate the images on the right.

3 - with no antialiasing. No good as too jaggy and corners not smooth.

4 - with anti-aliasing. Straight lines are too fuzzy as they are 2 pixel wide rather than 1.

Is there a way to do this with the path tool or any other way with the GIMP, or should I try some alternative to the GIMP?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer...

Edited to add: The link was broken but is still available on wayback machine.

https://web.archive.org/web/20130628145542/http://gimpforums.com/thread-1-pixel-wide-line-with-feathering

Comment: Since your question was answered on your GIMP forum post, would you add a summary of the solution here? I read through the forum post and was going to try to sum it up here, but to be honest I don't understand most of the information.

Comment: In essence, path has to be on half-pixel coordinates for an odd width path.

Comment: The link is broken. Can you please reproduce the contents here?

Answer (score 1):

Zoom in a lot, so that one pixel of the image being worked on is the size of your fingertip, and use the 1-pixel size brush.   If you click on one pixel, hold down the shift key then click somewhere else, you'll get an straight clean line, and it's fairly easy to make it perfectly horizontal or vertical.